# MySQL not working after Kubuntu upgrade

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have just upgraded to Kubuntu 15.04 and MySQL is no longer working properly. The error is:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

I have checked and there is no mysqld.sock file at that location (and no directory '`var/run/mysqld`'). I've tried creating a directory at '`var/run/mysqld`' and using chmod to make it writable by all, then restarting MySQL using 'sudo service mysql restart', but this doesn't solve the problem.

MySQL seems to be running (it's coming up as loaded & active when I run 'sudo service mysql status'). There's nothing in the MySQL error log.

I can't find any mysqld.sock file at all (did a search across the whole file system).

Any solutions before I give up and purge/reinstall mysql would be gratefully appreciated!

EDIT to add:

The MySQL process itself isn't in the process list. No errors are thrown when I start/restart MySQL using 'sudo service mysql', and /var/log/mysql/error.log is empty.

Comment: Looks like mysql is not running. try to check if you find a mysql process in your precess list.

Comment: Hmm - you're right - there's no mysql process. How can I fix that? 'sudo service mysql status' claims it's working and 'sudo service mysql restart' doesn't seem to throw any errors.

Comment: Try to start the process with `sudo service mysql start` and look if you get an error message.

Comment: No error message when I do that, but still no process.

Comment: look at `/var/log/` if you find some mysql logfiles.

Comment: /var/log/mysql/error.log is empty

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by changing the permissions on /var/lib/mysql and then running "mysqld" at the command line

So presumably some sort of permissions screw-up that happened as part of the Kubuntu upgrade.